# How to disable Hosttech Website block

Tags: web-server, hosting

I am hosting a website on www.hosttech.at. The page was blocked because it had a malware. Before removing it, I created a backup of the page. After fixing it, the site was unblocked successfully. But then I deleted an important file and restored this backup. The problem is, this restore also restored the website blocked.

Blocking is like you call the domain and it always redirects to page.blocked.php in httpdocs. I searched the whole directory but I didn't find the name of the file in any other file. Does anyone know how this host applies the blocking? Because hosttech's website does say that the website isn't blocked because I accidently restored the block by myself.

Also, if this helps, the website is using wordpress on the server host.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file? Files starting with a . are hidden in Unix, and this particular file provides directives to the webserver to override normal operation (if support is configured - which is common)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I didn't know these are hidden but I am using the webclient filemanager of the host where the .htaccess file doesn't seem to be hidden.